# Waffle revertedWith() matcher docs misleading?

Tags: solidity, waffle

In the Waffle documentation [here](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#revert-with-message), it shows that revertedWith() can be used with a regular expression. When used I am presented with an error claiming otherwise, already wasted too much time on this one, so I will proceed with the simpler .reverted matcher.

Just hoping someone out there could clear this one up, I can't see where I might have set this up wrong but...

Here is the error, the test was written exactly as the docs show to use it

```
await expect(token.checkRole('ADMIN')).to.be.revertedWith(/AccessControl: account .* is missing role .*/);
```

[image: error image]